# How to listen to key presses like "Close", "Reply", "Fwd", etc. on Mac?

Tags: macos, usb, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Before I upgrade to MacOS Catalina (Beta), I used to use [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) to listen for "those keys".  That's the only reason that why I was using USB Overdrive, along with Hammerspoon & Karabiner that I am already using.

I wonder if there are any tools / "programmable" way to listen to key presses for "those keys", so that I could further add more keyboard shortcuts.

I thought that as Karabiner is listening at a low level, as the EventViewer cannot receive the key presses, there will be no way to capture it -- however USB overdrive did it.

**Question**: Is there a way to listen to key presses from a USB keyboard? (The more "global" it is (i.e. without focusing a certain window / text box), the better)

P.S. For "those keys", I think those are are subset of HIC Consumer page, that should fire 2 keycodes which the first one is `0x0c`? ([Reference](https://source.android.com/devices/input/keyboard-devices))

P.P.S. I have also tried installing WireShark, however `tcpdump -D` doesn't show me `XHC20` interface, which I think listening to USB ports isn't possible anymore on Catalina?